# kalman filter matrices

Tags: dynamic-programming, bayesian-network, kalman-filter

I would like to apply a kalman filter on data I receive from a sensor, i.e. a lightsensor. I have 3 light sensors, 1 for each axis. I am grouping all the data from the three sensors in 1 formula.

My question:
How do i determine the values/content of the two matrices Fk and Bk? These are  related to P, Q and R covariant matrices.
I know it has to do with covariant matrices, but I'd need some more explanation.

[image: formula]

Comment: The matricies F and B are not related to to P Q or R.  F and B define the dynamics of your system.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you want to do with the light sensors? Do you want to smooth them out? Do you want to estimate range?